# jQuery -- How did I get here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must have used someone's existing code as a framework, and I developed a jQuery/JavaScript application I now need to use. It works fine if invoked from within the following code but I need to pass values for `nnn` from elsewhere in the page. Because I don't understand jQuery structure well enough, my efforts so far have failed.

```
<script>
$(function() {
.
.
.
  var BuildTree = function(centralID) {
    ...
  }
  BuildTree(nnn);
});
```

I want to do something like:

```
function BuildTree(...) {
...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: just get rid of the var = part, and change it to function BuildTree(centralID) {...}

Comment: You need to be more clear in your question.  How are things failing?  What do you expect to happen? What have you tried?

Comment: BuildTree is a function/var within the parent function. You can't access it from the outside. Just like you can't access private variables from the outside. Look into jQuery plugins. You need to take the time to learn and understand them. You can create your own options and set them from the outside. It's most likely what you will want to use.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  The declaration of BuildTree you have now will work just fine so there is no need to change it.  What problem do you have?

Comment: You're declaring your BuildTree function within a function, and it only exists within the scope of the function around it - therefore, you cannot call it from outside that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with scope, you're defining BuildTree inside the scope of the function you're passing to jQuery (or $ in this case).

This is a problem in terms of javascript and no jQuery, functions define a scope, what it means is that what you define inside a funcion lives inside of it.

```
function test() {
    var variable = 2;    //variable within the scope of test
}
variable //undefined
```

So, if you need to use it outside, you could define it outside the function and then use it inside or do something like:

```
$(function(){
...
    window.BuildTree = BuildTree //global scope
...
});
```

Also be careful with the caps, it means you're defining a Constructor, by javascript standars

Comment: Thanks. I later found in jQuery Pocket Reference that this is a common form for jQuery applications. In my case, I'll be able to use it as it stands, by simply calling the page and passing the necessary ID in a query string. I still don't understand what the purpose of that format (function within function) is, but I'll get by.

Comment: The idea behind that particular pattern is that you're passing a handler to jQuery so it can execute it whenever the page loads. It's the same that: `$(document).ready(handler)` (more here http://api.jquery.com/ready/). In other cases it's to declare a namespace, one example: http://dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the BuildTree function is limited to the scope of the outermost function. You simply need to move the function definition outside of the `$(function() {` function.

```
 var BuildTree = function(centralID) {
   ...
  }

$(function() {
  BuildTree(nnn);
});
BuildTree(nnn); // call it again.
```

There is no (major) difference between

```
var FunctionA = function () {

}
```

and

```
function FunctionA() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has function scope, which means that variables defined inside of a function are not accessible outside of that function. Anything that is declared inside of the jQuery function will not be accessible outside of the function.

```
$(function() {
  //anything defined in here will not be accessible outside of this jQuery function
  var foo = 'bar';
  var buildTree = function(centralId) {
  };
});

//this will be undefined since it was declared inside of the jQuery function
buildTree(1);
//this will also be undefined
console.log(foo);
```

If you want to access the buildTree function, you need to do so inside of the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

If BuildTree is just a function, you shouldn't need to put it inside `$(function() {`. You should just be able to do this:

```
<script>
function BuildTree(centralId) {
    // do stuff
}
</script>
```

Now you should be able to call this function from anywhere in the page. If you want BuildTree to be invoked when the DOM finishes loading, just do this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    BuildTree(1234);
});
</script>
```